# How to convert list to strings in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list:

```
x = ['nm0000131', 'nm0000432', 'nm0000163']
```

And I would like to convert it to:

```
'nm0000131', 
'nm0000432', 
'nm0000163'
```

e.g: I would like convert a list of strings (`x`) to 3 independent strings.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a list `x` you are trying to convert to what??

Comment: try `",".join(x)`

Comment: Try `x = ['nm0000131', 'nm0000432', 'nm0000163']
str1 = ','.join(x)
print(str1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want three separate string you can use `for` loop.

Try the following code:

```
x = ['nm0000131', 'nm0000432', 'nm0000163']
for value in x:
    print(value)
```

Output will be like:

```
nm0000131                                                                                                                      
nm0000432                                                                                                                      
nm0000163
```

The following code will display an output like `"nm0000131" ,"nm0000432" ,"nm0000163"`:

```
x = ['nm0000131', 'nm0000432', 'nm0000163']
str1 = '" ,"'.join(x)
x = '"'+str1+'"'
print(x)
```

As you mentioned in the comment I would like to include some more points to my answer.
If you want to get the key-value pairs then try the following code.

```
y = {'131': 'a', '432': 'b', '163': 'c'}
w = []
for key, value in y.items():
    w.append(value)

print(w)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Good catch but this code convert a list for 1 only string: '"nm0000131" ,"nm0000432" ,"nm0000163"'

I would like convert for 3 strings like: 'nm0000131', 'nm0000432', 'nm0000163'

Comment: I have changed my code so look at it. I think this is what you are looking for. If my answer is correct one then click on the tick to accept my answer because which will help some one later.

Comment: Got it,
Now I'm working with a list and a dictionary, I would like from the value of the list to look up the corresponding in the dictionary and create a list with the corresponding, like:

x = ['131', '432', '163']
y = {'131':a, '432': b, '163': c}
Output: w = ['a', 'b', 'c']

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `for loop` and iterate through the `key-value pairs` then assign the value into another `array`.

Comment: I have updated my answer :)

Comment: You are welcome. Hi friend if my answer helped you then accept it.